# How can I suppress unneeded output from emacsclient?

Tags: io-redirection, emacs

I use emacs fairly regularly and am trying to configure my system to use emacsclient when possible.  To do this I have done the following:

In .bashrc:

```
EDITOR='emacsclient -ca emacs'
VISUAL='emacsclient -ca emacs'
```

I then also installed an alternative for /usr/bin/editor that points to /usr/local/bin/emacsclient.wrapper that has the following:

```
 #!/bin/sh
 #Start emacs client
 /usr/bin/emacsclient -ca emacs $1
```

For the most part this works great.  However, when emacsclient is launched from the terminal, it often spews out text I don't need.  Notably:

```
$ editor 
Waiting for Emacs...
$
```

Or, when emacs isn't already started and emacclient has to fall back to starting emacs itself:

```
emacsclient: can't find socket; have you started the server?
To start the server in Emacs, type "M-x server-start".
```

What can I do to surpress this output?  I've tried changing my emacs wrapper to

```
     #!/bin/sh
     #Start emacs client
     /usr/bin/emacsclient -ca emacs $1 &> /dev/null
```

but this didn't help.  I didn't try editing EDITOR or VISUAL since I don't have any ideas other than this standard redirection.

Comment: Replace `$1` by `"$@"`. The quotes are needed to pass file names containing spaces and other special characters, and `"$@"` will pass all arguments to `emacsclient` in case you ever want to edit several files at once or pass `+LINE FILENAME` to open a file at a certain line number.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In general:

```
program >/dev/null 2>&1
```

will force the output (`STDOUT`) of `program` to `/dev/null` and redirects `STDERR` to `STDOUT`.  So try:

```
/usr/bin/emacsclient -ca emacs $1 >/dev/null 2>&1
```

Comment: Gah!  Immediately upon reading your response did I realize that &> is a bashism and was never going to work with #!/bin/sh.

Comment: @Steven Oh, good call. I tried it in `sh` to make sure, but `sh` is symlinked to `bash` on my computer